# To show div block after pressing preview button - magento 2 Form using KO JS

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I'm trying to hide a div block, it should show after I press preview button, can anyone help?

Code:

> gift-message-form.html

```
<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="secondary">
        <button type="submit" class="action action-update" data-bind="
                attr: {title: $t('Update')},
                click: $data.submitOptions.bind($data)">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="action action-cancel" data-bind="
                attr: {title: $t('Cancel')},
                click: $data.hideFormBlock.bind($data)">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Cancel'"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="action action-preview" data-bind="
                attr: {title: $t('Preview')},
                click: function($data){ viewPreviewOfMessage($data)};">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Preview'"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-bind="visible: showPreviewOfMessage">
    <img src="">
    <span>To</span>
    <span>Message</span>
    <span>from</span>
</div>
```

> gift-message.js (view folder under web)

```
    viewPreviewOfMessage: function() {
        this.showPreviewOfMessage(false);
                    //document.getElementById('preview_of_gift_message').innerHTML = getObservabale('message');
    },
                
    showPreviewOfMessage: function(){
        return true;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button class="action action-preview" data-bind="
            attr: {title: $t('Preview')},
            click: showPreviewOfMessage">
     <span data-bind="i18n: 'Preview'"></span>
</button>
```

and:

```
<div data-bind="visible: previewVisible">
    <img src="">
    <span>To</span>
    <span>Message</span>
    <span>from</span>
</div>
```

In js component:

```
previewVisible: ko.observable(),

showPreviewOfMessage: function(){
    this.previewVisible(true);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it, this is working

gift-message-form.html

```
<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="secondary">
        <button type="submit" class="action action-update" data-bind="
                attr: {title: $t('Update')},
                click: $data.submitOptions.bind($data)">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="action action-cancel" data-bind="
                attr: {title: $t('Cancel')},
                click: $data.hideFormBlock.bind($data)">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Cancel'"></span>
        </button>
        <button data-bind="
                attr: {title: $t('Preview')},
                click: $data.switchPreviewOfMessage.bind($data)">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Preview'"></span>
        </button>
        
    </div>
</div>
<div data-bind="visible: formPreviewVisibility() || resultBlockVisibility()" style="background-image: url('./images/giftcardimage.jpg')">

    <p>hello</p>
    
</div>
```

declare formPreviewVisibility:null, in view JS file and add .observe('formPreviewVisibility') in initilize function and define the function like this

```
switchPreviewOfMessage: function () {
            if (!this.model.getObservable('alreadyAdded')()) {
                this.formPreviewVisibility(!this.formPreviewVisibility());
            } else {
                this.resultBlockVisibility(!this.resultBlockVisibility());
            }
        },
```